# Related rates using law of cosines, Two side of a triangle having...

Tags: calculus

Two sides of a triangle are 15cm and 20cm long respectively. 
$A)$ How fast is the third side increasing if the angle between the given sidesis 60 degrees and is increasing at the rate of $2^\circ/sec$? $B)$ How fast is the area increasing?

$A)$ I used $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\theta)$ so I got the missing side $c=28.72$ is this right? and then I get confused with the implicit differentiation where, $2c$$\frac{dc}{dt}$ $= $2a$\frac{da}{dt}$ $+$ $2b$$\frac{db}{dt}$ $-$ $2\cos(\theta)$ ($a$$\frac{db}{dt}$+$b$$\frac{da}{db})$ I know that 60degrees is $\frac{Pi}{3}$ to radiance but I keep on getting the wrong answer, they said it's supposed to be $\frac{dc}{dt}=0.5$ I don't know what to substitute with $\frac{da}{dt}$ and $\frac{db}{dt}$ is it the $2^\circ/sec$ ? I'm so confused.

$B)$ I also get confuse here on what formula to use.

Answer (score 1):

In part a), $\theta$ is the only variable mentioned as changing.

So $\dfrac{d\theta}{dt} = 2^{\circ}/\text{sec} = \dfrac{\pi}{90}\text{rad/sec}$ and $\dfrac{da}{dt} = \dfrac{db}{dt} = 0 \text{cm/sec}$.

Can you show what you plugged into the formula to get $c \approx 28.72$? I got $c = 5\sqrt{13} \approx 18.03$.

Also, when you differentiated $c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta$ you should get $2c\dfrac{dc}{dt} = 2ab\sin\theta \dfrac{d\theta}{dt}$

In part b), note that the area of a triangle is $A = \dfrac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta$.

Comment: so the answer in A) is not 0.5?

Comment: may i know what your C is? is it 28.72?

Comment: For $a$ I got $\dfrac{dc}{dt} = \dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{39}} \text{cm/sec} \approx 0.503 \text{cm/sec}$.

Comment: last question, why didn't you use product rule with the $ab$ in the $-2abcos(theta)$ ? because it's a constant is that right?

Comment: Yes. If $a$ and $b$ weren't constant, we would have $2c\dfrac{dc}{dt} = 2a\dfrac{da}{dt}+2b\dfrac{2b}{dt} - 2b\cos\theta\dfrac{da}{dt} - 2a\cos\theta\dfrac{db}{dt} + 2ab\sin\theta \dfrac{d\theta}{dt}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming sides $a,b$ do not change in length ( no constraints given) , differentiate

$$c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta$$

$$ 2 c \dot c = - 2 a b  \sin \theta \, \omega $$

$$  \dot c = -  \dfrac{a b}{c}  \sin \theta \, \omega $$

Similarly for area A

$$ A = \frac12 a b \sin \theta $$

$$ \dot A = \frac{ab}2 \cos \theta\,\omega. $$